# Change parent window location of iframe based on clicked div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Trying to cross reference a few items on 2 different platforms (wordpress and shopify).

Just to be clear, i have managed to make parent window location change on click with this code

```
document.domain = 'domain.com';
$(window).load(function(){
$("#frame").contents().find('.item').click(function(){
        window.top.location = "http://google.com";
        });
});
```

Now to the main problem.
There is a hidden div with list of all posts i'd need visitors to be sent to if appropriate element inside iframe would be clicked. List items are set up as a's

```
<a href="dynamiclink.com" class="itemstrack" id="letterprefix<?php dynamic-id-as-numbers-string?>" >1</a>
```

in the iframe, there are divs with exactly same dynamic id's

```
<div style="color:#008c99; cursor:pointer;" class="itempass" id="letterprefix{{dynamic-id-as-numbers-string}}">Whatever</div>
```

And here is js i'm trying to use

```
document.domain = 'domain.com';
$(window).load(function(){
 $("a.itemstrack").each(function(){
    var trackid = $(this).attr('id');
    var trackidhref = $(this).attr('href');

    $("#frame").contents().find('#letterprefix' +trackid).click(function(){
        window.top.location = trackidhref;
        });
    });
});
```

also tried following code in iframe contents

```
document.domain = 'domain.com';
  $(window).load(function(){
    $(".itempass").each(function(){
    var varid = $(this).attr("id");
      $(this).click(function(){
      var newloc = $(window.parent.document).find("#" + varid);
        window.top.location = newloc;
      });
    });
  });
```

p.s.
i don't want to use shopify api because of limit on calls

Comment: Is the click event handler firing when item is clicked? What happens? Do those elements exist when code runs? Seems like you need a load event handler on the iframe before looking inside it. Also does href have absolute or relative url? Really not much troubleshooting information given

Comment: Why is this not handled by the document inside the frame?

Comment: In your updated code for the iframe content, i think 'variantid' should be 'varid'.

Comment: yes. missed this one here, but vars match in actual code.

Comment: `.find()` returns a jQuery Object. You want the href attribute of the `a` tag. Try: `var newloc = $('#' + varid, window.parent.document).attr('href');`

Comment: nope... no go. Basic redirect stopped working too for some reason